# Async run for javascript by using listeners

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, listener

I have two functions, the names are Function3, Function4, Function3 will send request to server side to get jsondata by using ajax, which, however, will take about 3 seconds to complete. Function4 is a common function which will wait for Function3's result and then action.
My code puts below:

```
  function ajaxRequest(container)
  {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Home/GetResult",
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {
            container.append(data.message);
        }
    });
  }

  var eventable = {
    on: function (event, cb) {
        $(this).on(event, cb);
    },
    trigger: function (event) {
        $(this).trigger(event);
    }
}

var Function3 = {
    run: function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            ajaxRequest($(".container1"));
            self.trigger('done');
        }, 500);
    }
}

var Function4 = {
    run: function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".container1").append("Function4 complete");
            self.trigger('done');
        },500);
    }
}

$.extend(Function3, eventable);
$.extend(Function4, eventable);

Function3.on('done', function (event) {
    Function4.run();
});

Function4.on('done', function () {
    $(".container1").append("All done");
});

Function3.run();
```

But now the problem is, when I start the code , it always show me the result as : first will appear "Function4 complete", then "All done" follows, 3 seconds later, "Function3 complete" will appear.
That's out of my expection because my expection is "Function3 complete" comes first, "Function4 complete" comes second and "All done" is expected as the last one.

Anyone can help me on this? thx in advice.

**EDIT:**
I have included all the functions above now.
Also, you can check the js script in JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sporto/FYBjc/light/
I have replaced the function in JSFiddle from a common array push action to ajax request,
then all things run out of my expection.

Comment: Can you complete your code? Or put up a JSFiddle for it.

Comment: @MarkGabriel Have added.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `Function4()` from within the success-function that follows from the ajax-request that `Function3()` makes. That way `Function4` is always executed after `Function3`.

And might I suggest more suggestive function names:)

And I don't even think you need all the timeouts then

Comment: yes, your suggestion is correct. but I don't think it follows the listener pattern.

Answer (score 0):

`Function4` completes first because `ajaxRequest` or `$.ajax` calls are asynchronous and will the sequence of the code will continue while waiting for the ajax reply.

```
var Function3 = {
    run: function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            ajaxRequest($(".container1")); 
            //code sequence continues on while ajax hasn't replied yet
            self.trigger('done');
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

When `Function3` triggers `done`, `Function4` will now run. And will append `"All done"` because all of this happened first before the ajax got the chance to reply and run its `success` function.

If you want them to be sequential, run `Function4` in **$.ajax's success function**.
Or, you can signal `Function3` to be done after `$.ajax's success`. That way, Function3 will only really be "done" after the AJAX has succeeded.

**EDIT:**
We mean here:

```
success: function (data) {
    container.append(data.message);
    //here you need to call Function4, to make sure it only runs after Function3's ajax-request has finished
}
```

Comment: ok, got't, I think maybe listener pattern is not used in such scenario.

Comment: Ajax-requests are a whole special thing of their own. Because they are asynch, you can never know when they are done. That's why, for ajax-requests they have those special succes-function (that is the listenerer for the ajax-request, to tackle that issue.